# golang http server tailing logs kubeapi proxy

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

Maybe anyone faced a similar problem. We have a kubeapi proxy which impersonates users using sso.
Kubectl tool works just fine with any commands unless you do tail `-f`

I do see that app data is coming back every 1-5 seconds, but to output it takes ~ 45 seconds.

We use http/server from standard go packages and our proxy is based of https://github.com/ericchiang/kube-oidc/issues

TCP Dump attached. Thanks

[image]